# Why is my custom object not persisted by onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android

When the activity gets called for the very first time, it is called with an extra in the intent. The extra is received and stored in the data member:

```
class EditBlindScheduleActivity extends Activity
{
  private BlindSchedule blindSchedule;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {  // Not recreating, first load.
      blindSchedule = (BlindSchedule) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("blindSchedule");
    }
```

There is a simple if/else to determine if we have the `blindSchedule` object or not.

```
if (blindSchedule == null) {
  setTitle("Create Blind Schedule");
} else {
  setTitle("Edit Blind Schedule");
}
```

When I load the activity for the first time, indeed, the title is "Edit Blind Schedule", meaning there is a blindSchedule object.

Unfortunately, when I rotate the screen twice the title reads "Create Blind Schedule", meaning the blindSchedule object is null and has failed to be persisted.

### Why is my blindSchedule object not being persisted, and what can I do about it?

Full code follows:

```
public class EditBlindScheduleActivity extends Activity {

  private BlindSchedule blindSchedule;

  Boolean creating;  // Creating or updating?

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_blind_schedule);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {  // Not recreating, first load.
      blindSchedule = (BlindSchedule) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("blindSchedule");
    }

    if (blindSchedule == null) {
      creating = true;
      setTitle("Create Blind Schedule");
    } else {
      creating = false;
      setTitle("Edit Blind Schedule");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    blindSchedule = (BlindSchedule) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("blindSchedule");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("blindSchedule", blindSchedule);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve the saved custom object in `onCreate` in your case.

According to [Official Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

`onRestoreInstanceState` is called  after `onStart` by which time your `setTitle` has already been called.

Add an else part to the `if (savedInstanceState == null)` and retrieve `blindSchedule` in there same way as you do for your `getIntent`

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) 
{  // Not recreating, first load.
  blindSchedule = (BlindSchedule) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("blindSchedule");
}
else
{
  blindSchedule = (BlindSchedule) savedInstanceState.getSerializableExtra("blindSchedule");
}
```

Comment: So is the override of onRestoreInstanceState superfluous in this case?  What is it useful for?

Comment: If you want to do something after `onStart` then you can do it there.